# Como armazenar uma variável em um trecho específico do template?

Tags: angular

Estou acessando um dado de um objeto:

```
<div *ngFor="let objeto of objetos">
    <div 
      [ngClass]="{'minha-classe': !!pegaDados(objeto.id).isValido}">
        {{ pegaDados(objeto.id).nome }}
    </div>
</div>
```

Mas o tempo e o processamento gasto puxando os dados da API com a função `pegaDados()` é muito alto. Como eu posso armazenar esses dados dentro de uma das duas `<div>` para utilizar durante a execução de cada laço?

Comment: Cara, blza através da **string interpolation {{ }}** você consegue executar Javascript no Html, mas, isso não é indicado, ainda mais quando a função é assíncrona. Html é estrutura e Ts é código.

Comment: Meu foco não é na função assíncrona em si, mas em como eu posso salvar os dados de uma função genérica em uma variável no bloco que eu vou trabalhar

Comment: Não entendi bem sua dúvida, **let objeto** já não está guardando os dados?

Comment: mas como eu posso salvar os dados retornados pela função `pegaDados()` em uma variável?

Comment: Seria bom inserir o código do Ts da função pegaDados().

Comment: já tentou fazer uma variável receber a função? Tipo `const getData = pegarDados()`, e depois chamar no angular com a interpolação `{{ getData.nome }}`?

Comment: @LeAndrade a função retorna um observable de um objeto `interface Resposta{id: number, isValido: boolean, nome: string}` da seguinte forma: `pegaDados(id:number){return this.httpService.get(this.API_ADDRESS + "/" + id);}`

Comment: @adventistaam não se aplica, estou tentando guardar os dados no template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como o pessoal comentou, iniciar este processamento no template não é o mais indicado mas focando na sua dúvida diretamente você poderia fazer da seguinte forma:

```
<div *ngFor="let objeto of objetos">
    <!-- Criar um array de uma única posição c/o resultado do pegarDados() -->
    <ng-container *ngFor="let temp of [pegarDados(objeto)]">
    <div [ngClass]="{'minha-classe': !!temp.isValido}">
        {{ temp.nome }}
    </div>
</div>
```

Não é uma solução elegante mas funcionaria no contexto que você propôs. Vale lembrar que você pode inicializar este processamento em algum momento no ciclo de vida do seu componente e utilizar por exemplo, o `async pipe` para renderizar os dados no template.

Voltando a questão da variável no template, há uma outra referência interessante utilizando diretiva: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38582293/how-to-declare-a-variable-in-a-template-in-angular